# NgFor Button with router link inside

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-router

i want to ask if there is a way for do this

```
<button *ngFor="let link of links" routerLink="{{link.value}} <<<<  (i want to insert value from array to this
">{{link.Name}}</paper-button>

links = [
{Name:'Menu1' , value:'/Menu1'},
{Name:'Menu2' , value:'/Menu2'},
]
```

and in my router-module,

```
{ path: 'Menu1',  component: Menu1Component },
{ path: 'Menu2',  component: Menu2Component },
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

By using the notation `[routerLink]` instead of `routerLink`, you can pass instance properties to the value. In your case it would be:

```
<button *ngFor="let link of links" [routerLink]="link.value">
    {{link.Name}}
</paper-button>
```

Comment: Works the same with `{{}}` as long as it's only a string value.